# How to dock an application in the Windows desktop?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, taskbar, docking

I would like to develop a small notifications application for Windows in .NET that docks on the right/left side of the screen (not consuming more than 300px), should always be visible and force the rest of windows to not overlap this application (something like the old Office taskbar or Vista's Sidebar). I have no idea where to start. Can it be done using XAML/WPF? Since I haven't even started coding any option is valid at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: This question has been answered very well in another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most reliable way would be to register your application as an Application Desktop Toolbar (AppBar).

You will need to interop to do this, here is a Code Project article on doing this with C#, it should be a fair starting point. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You want to create an [AppBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108(v=VS.85).aspx)!

Basically call SHAppBarMessage() with ABM_NEW, ABM_QUERYPOS, ABM_SETPOS and ABM_ACTIVATE, in that order.

If you want to do it from managed code, you'll have to write the interop yourself, or use [this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHAppBarMessage) from pinvoke.net.