# Windows API to attach window to the left or to right of desktop

Tags: windows, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dock an application in the Windows desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792024/how-to-dock-an-application-in-the-windows-desktop)

I need the behavior of window like Google Desktop does.
Main window of Google Desktop can be attached to the left or to the right of desktop and DOESN'T overlap desktop icons.
Icons automatically move from this place!
If maximize another window it uses only available space and doesn't use area took by attached Google Desktop window.
It work on Windows XP as well

What API does Google Desktop use for such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI element you're talking about is an application bar, or appbar for short. It's created and operated by using the API function [`SHAppBarMessage'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For instance, to create a new appbar, you sent it the `ABM_NEW` message with a message identifier Windows can use to communicate with it. To position the bar along one edge of the desktop, you send it the `ABM_SETPOS` message. There are quite a few messages defined; they're listed on the page I linked above.