# Fix the windows form on desktop using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to fix my vb form on the desktop. i don't want other windows to occupy the space which my form is fixed.

[image: The image shows that ticker showing on top of the screen]

Image Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qshI8.jpg

The image shows that ticker is on top of the screen. When other window(s)/application(s) opened that ticker should not override instead the new applications should open below to that ticker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register your application in AppBar (*Application Desktop Toolbar*).

To do this, you'll need to interop. 
[Here is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx) with C#. And [another one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3).

Comment: Thank you so much... AppBar helped a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that the form is always in front of others you have to set the attribute `TopMost` of the form to `True`. to bring it on front after showing just call the `Activate()` method.

Comment: i found another thread, that maybe also help you to achieve the prevention of space occupy: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792024/how-to-dock-an-application-in-the-windows-desktop)

Comment: This won't prevent other applications from getting in the way of the App, this just means your form that u set this will be top most out of them.

Comment: the link to the other thread i posted shows a solution how to get this working