# Docking Like Mac OSX Dock in WPF

Tags: wpf, docking

As [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf) on the link is a nice docking application but I need something like Mac OSX dock, It Docks at a side without taking the screen, and when we need it it's there.

Please tell me docking solution that does not take up the screen space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shot in the dark, based on what I imagine you're trying to achieve.  I'm going to assume you're running a Window based full trust local app.  Trust probably won't matter, just setting context.

There are three pieces to the solution I'm imagining:

```
Window1.xaml (your main app window)
 <Window blah blah>
  <Grid>
  <!--Your application content-->
    <local:PseudoDock VerticalAlignment='Bottom' />
  </Grid>
</Window>

PseudoDock.xaml
<UserControl Height='5'>
 <UserControl.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property='FrameworkElement.IsMouseOver'>
   <Setter Property='Height' Value='NaN' />
  </Trigger>
 </UserControl.Triggers>
 <ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal' />
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <Button Command='{Binding Path=Command}'>
     <StackPanel>
      <Image Source='{Binding Path=Icon}' />
      <TextBlock Source='{Binding Path=Label}' />
     </StackPanel>
    </Button>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

The important thing about the dock is that it's 5 pixels tall, which is unnoticeable at the bottom, and has a mouseover which raises it to full height.  (You could also try setting an explicit height, I imagine that setting the height to NaN will have it measure against its children but I could be wrong).

Lastly, the structure of the items which make up the dock:

```
DockItem.cs
class DockItem{
 ICommand Command{get;set;}
 String Label{get;set;}
 ImageSource Icon{get;set;}
}
```

(After comment exchange)
If you're looking to have it transparently sit over the desktop you'll need to set it this way:

```
<Window WindowStyle='None' Background='Transparent' State='Maximized'>
```

Comment: Thanks For the Solution, and sorry that I failed to explain what I wanted, Here's it "I Just Need it to dock to any side of the desktop and should behave like the Mac OSX Dock or the Dell Dock". Sorry for the trouble and once again, Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, answer updating now to reflect requirements.