# How to limit bottom window full screen max y position on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

What I'm trying to do is to create software which will behave as windows task bar.

So my point is that I want software that will be visible above task bar and when you maximize another app window it will not go over it.

[image: Sample image]

So i want that any other software when in maximized state to be till the red line. Red line will be my software which will be visible at any time except when other software is in full screen.

So is there a way to do this.
C# preferred.

What I want to know is  how to do it, I presume it needs to be done through WinApi, but I don't know even how call this app behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Applications can be "docked" to the left or right side of the screen (think of a "Buddy list" in an instant messenger), so perhaps you could use this technique to "dock" a window to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to register your application as an App Bar. Use `SHAppBarMessage`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf) for sample C# code.

Comment: So that nobody gives you the obligatory "that's WPF, this is winforms", a link to the original project that will work with winforms: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Just something to think about: toolbars/appbars (stuff that gets integrated in the taskbar) are pretty much rendered obsolete or unusable by Windows 7's new unified taskbar.

If your potential market includes Windows 7 users it might be wise to check out the alternatives like sidebar integration or some kind of dock that sits on the opposite side of the screen wrt the taskbar.