# How to create a special docked window outside of the desktop (like microsoft test manager)

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, desktop, docking

When using the Test Runner of Microsoft Test Manager, it creates a window which is docked to the edge of the screen. This window seems to sit "outside" the desktop area so that the start menu, etc don't overlap it, and when you maxmize another app, it takes up the remainder of the screen and this docked window stays in place.

Some Ascii art to explain

Normal windows Desktop

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 |
| Icon                                            |
|                                           Icon  |
| Icon                                            |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| start           <taskbar>                   2pm |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

With MTM runner

```
+----------+--------------------------------------+
|          |                                      |
|          | Icon                                 |
|          |                                Icon  |
|   MTM    | Icon                                 |
|  Runner  |                                      |
|  special |                                      |
|  window  |                                      |
+          |--------------------------------------+
|          | start        <taskbar>           2pm |
+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to do something similar to this in my application, but I can't figure out what to google for or what the terms might be. The app is a C# WPF app, but I'm happy to P/Invoke into C or C++ if neccessary.

Comment: This is called appbar. In pure winapi you may use SHAppBarMessage message to create appbar. But in c#....I have no idea. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do AppBar docking (to screen edge, like WinAmp) in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf)