# c# AppBar switching users

Tags: c#, winapi, locking, appbar, switch-user

I'm writing an App Bar using win32 calls like `SHAppBarMessage`. Currently I handle this behavior by doing this:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += this.sessionSwitchEventHandler;
```

Where the event handler has some code:

```
    private void SysEventsCheck(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
            case SessionSwitchReason.ConsoleConnect:
                function_to_dock_app_bar();
                break;
        }
    }
```

This works just fine for the `SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock` case, triggered by when the user locks their machine and then unlocks it. However, when the user chooses the Switch User option, and then logs back in later (triggering the `SessionSwitchReason.ConsoleConnect` case), all of the windows move around erratically and the AppBar is moved to an incorrect location.

Does anyone have insight or a workaround to this? The function that handles the docking is similar to any other win32 wpf app bar ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf))

Comment: I'm sorry, do you expect me to upload an entire c# solution? This is not a one file program even at its very smallest.

Comment: I would like to ask again, how could I post more code to make this completely replicable? I am unable to post a whole solution, and this is not an issue that can be presented in one file / snippet.

Comment: Never mind then. Good luck.